# Spring Manual Wiring Validator Error

Tags: spring

Initially, I am able to get a successful validation result using the below autowired code, but encountered below error with below new manual wiring code.  Appreciate if anyone could advise what is wrong here.

**Original Code (working fine):**

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("employeeFormValidator")  //Custom validator implement Spring Framework Validator class
private Validator validator;     // Spring Framework Validator class

@InitBinder
private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(validator);
}

<beans:bean id="employeeFormValidator" class="com.project.spring.form.validator.EmployeeFormValidator" />
```

**New code (encountered below error):**

```
  private EmployeeFormValidator employeeFormValidator;

    public void setEmployeeFormValidator(EmployeeFormValidator employeeFormValidator){
        this.employeeFormValidator = employeeFormValidator;
    }

    @InitBinder
    private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(employeeFormValidator);
    }

    <beans:bean id="employeeFormValidator" class="com.project.spring.form.validator.EmployeeFormValidator" />
    <beans:bean id="employeeController" class="com.project.spring.form.controllers.EmployeeController">
        <beans:property name="employeeFormValidator" value="employeeFormValidator" />
    </beans:bean>
```

**Error:**

```
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: 

Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.project.spring.form.validator.EmployeeFormValidator' for property 'employeeFormValidator'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.project.spring.form.validator.EmployeeFormValidator] for property 'employeeFormValidator': no matching editors or conversion strategy found at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
```

Comment: Use `ref` instead of `value` in your `property` element. You want to inject a bean **ref**erence not an actual value of `employeeFormValidator`.

Comment: Thank you Deinum.  Did not notice i used "value".  Solved it with ref.  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<beans:property name="employeeFormValidator" value="employeeFormValidator" />
```

should be

```
<beans:property name="employeeFormValidator" ref="employeeFormValidator" />
```